# NoBufferSpaceAvailable when sending data to socket

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, network-protocols

I use on a connected socket on my server something like this to send data to the client:

```
IAsyncResult asyncRes = connectionSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, length, SocketFlags.None, 
     out error, new AsyncCallback(SendDataDone), signalWhenDataSent);
```

As it seems, when there is a slow internet connection between the server and the client I receive an exception description like this: NoBufferSpaceAvailable

What exactly does this error mean ? The internal OS buffer for the socket `connectionSocket` is full ? What are the means to make it work. As a context where this appears is in a http proxy server. This might indicate, *I suppose*,  that the rate at which data is coming from the origin server is higher than the rate my server can handle with the proxy client. How would you deal with it ?

I am using tcp.

Comment: What protocol are you using? TCP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this problem is to correlate the way one reads from one socket to the speed one writes to the other socket because if you do no buffering you cannot write to a socket at a higher speed than the client connected at that end can read.

You one uses synchronous sockets the problem does not appear because they block as long as the operation is still pending but this is not the case with async calls.

Answer (score -1):

Exactly, most likely the kernel socket buffer holding outgoing data is full. You're sending too "fast" for the client. You can try to increase the send buffer size, but that does not guarantee you won't bump into this problem again.

The simple answer is that you should be prepared that a send operation might fail, and retry it later. It's not ideal to maintain an ever growing buffer inside you application either, but the origin server should also slow down if you stop receiving (depending on the TCP window size and your receive buffer size).

Comment: Send operations over TCP do not fail in the way you have described here. If the socket send buffer was full the send() would just block at the lowest level, and the async callback just wouldn't be called. He is running out of some other buffer space, e.g. async stuff. It may still be that he is running

Comment: @EJP actually they can fail with ENOBUFS if you use non-blocking operations. I indeed missed that he's using async stuff, though. That does not change the fact the application is trying to send too fast, which can be fixed by e.g. slowing down receiving from the origin server.